# sql removing part of a string to format a date

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have inherited a database from someone at work, and they have stored all dates in VARCHAR(). Normally I would just convert it to a datetime and move on. But it's stored in the format of  "Tuesday, June 19 2012 at 11:46:40 AM"  I am working with some scripts and date comparisons in PHP and SQL and I need to make this a usable date.

I tried converting it this way: by taking the old date and converting it into a separate field that I will rename when converted. when I run it, I get an error

```
 UPDATE ticket_backup
    SET new_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(submit_date AS DATETIME), 109)
```

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from binary/varbinary
>   string.

So now I am thinking I will need to remove a substring with using regular expression to remove what I don't need. I need to get it to the format of SQL server DATETIME standard of "2013-02-07 11:28:51"

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm at a roadblock and there are a lot of records I need to convert.

Comment: Looks like a valid format for PHP's `strtotime()` function - that would convert the data to a timestamp (integer) which you could then reformat with something like `date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $iTimestamp)` and use that to update the MySQL table... then it's already in the right format so it should be possible to just convert the data type. This is just theorycrafting for the moment though, I've not tested it.

Comment: Is the format of the column perfectly uniform? Or are there likely to be differences, eg extra space/padding, missing comma etc?

Comment: it is perfectly uniform. it was inserted by a formatted variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL dates.. always fun! Try this, should work so long as all rows have the same format as your demo row (e.g. a comma after the day):

```
UPDATE ticket_backup
    SET new_date = CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(submit_date as varchar(50)) ,
            PATINDEX('%,%',CAST(submit_date as varchar(50)) )+2 ,LEN(CAST(submit_date as varchar(50)) )),'at ', '') as datetime)
```

Comment: I get this error: Argument data type varbinary is invalid for argument 2 of patindex function.

Comment: So submit_date is a varbinary, not a varchar?

Comment: Yeah just needed an extra cast to varchar. As above. Is that how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

not complete but this is how i would approach it:

1. create a new date column
2. update all current values to get rid of the day part...

   update mytable set mydate = replace( mydate, 'Monday, ', '' );

   update mytable set mydate = replace( mydate, 'Tuesday, ', '' );

etc.

1. remove that 'at' word

   update mytable set mydate = replace( mydate, ' at ', '' );
2. try your conversion again

   UPDATE ticket_backup
       SET new_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(submit_date AS DATETIME), 109)
3. drop old column
4. rename new column

Comment: I would do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way it can be done, as simple as I think it can be made:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(RIGHT(submit_date,LEN(submit_date)-CHARINDEX(',',submit_date)),' at ',' '),109)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6075/1/0)